# AJAX ReadyState 4 Status 200 but responseText undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an `html` and `php` file:

`test.html`:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState==4 && req.status == 200) {
      var dat = req.reponseText;
      alert("Status text: " + req.statusText);
      alert("Response: " + dat);
    }
  }; 
req.open("GET", "info.php", true);
req.send();
```

and `info.php`:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Accessing `info.php` shows "test" as expected, but the `responseText` from the AJAX request is always undefined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TYPO TYPO TYPO

```
var dat = req.reponseText;
               ^^^
```